# On the "basis" of the space $C^\infty(a,b)$ of smooth functions

Tags: vector-spaces, smooth-functions, hamel-basis, schauder-basis

My math methods textbook (Hassani's *Mathematical Physics*) makes the following (I think dubious) claim:

> If we assume that a < 0 < b, then the set of monomials $1,x,x^2,...$ forms a basis for $C^∞(a,b)$, because, by Taylor’s theorem, any function belonging to $C^∞(a,b)$ can be expanded in an infinite power series about $x = 0$. Thus, this space is infinite-dimensional.

Now this claim seems to me dubious for two reasons:

(1) It does not use the notion of basis (I think the technical term is Hamel basis) previously defined: a basis is a linearly independent set of vectors which span the space (where span only involves finite linear combinations). $e^x$ for example is not representable as a finite linear combination of these monomials.

(2) Even if we did admit the generalized notion of basis (I think this is called a Schauder basis?) I don't think it's true that the monomials form a (Schauder) basis; as far as I know, it is not true that every element of $C^∞(a,b)$ is representable as a power series (the analytic functions are a proper subset of the smooth functions on $(a,b)$).

Am I correct in these two assessments or am I missing something? Note that I do not disagree with the statement about the space being infinite-dimensional (of course).

Comment: To talk about Schauder basis, you would need a norm on the space. Do you have one?

Comment: Schauder bases are for topological vector spaces not only normed vector spaces. If you copied the sentence correctly then yes this is very worrying, some confusion about basis, topological vector spaces, analyticity..

Comment: I have mixed feeling about it: there is the [Stone–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) telling from one side that you always could find a polynomial closed enough as desired to any continuous function, but from the other hand, there are [Non-analytic smooth function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function) which could behave as [Flat functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function). (...)

Comment: (...) were they are not analytical and a power series should always fail to fit with "infinitesimal accuracy" since matching a constant value in a non-zero measure interval would violate the [Identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) for power series. Try applying the Stone Weierstrass theorem to a flat function, I think that would give you your answer.